# LiveData<List<Child>> is not a subclass of LiveData<List<Parent>>

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an abstract ViewModel class,let's call it AbstractListViewModel.
It has a itemsList of type MutableLiveData < List < JSONObject > >. JSONObject has 2 children : JSONChildOne and JSONChildTwo. I would like to override the property in a AbstractViewModel child to type MutableLiveData< List < JSONChildOne > >.

I tried to override in the child class to MutableLiveData < List < JSONChildOne > >

AbstractListViewModel :

```
abstract val itemsList : MutableLiveData<List<JSONObject>>
```

ChildOneListViewModel :

```
override val itemsList =  MutableLiveData<List<JSONChildOne>>()
```

Property type is "MutableLiveData < List < JSONObject > > ", which is not a subtype of overriden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: Also worth reading: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that I don't know how to use that in Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, `List<Child>` does not extend `List<Parent>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) for a discussion about why).

You should use a generic argument in your `AbstractViewModel`, for example:

```
abstract class AbstractViewModel<T: JSONObject> {
    abstract val itemsList : MutableLiveData<List<T>>
}

class ChildOneListViewModel : AbstractViewModel<JSONChildOne> {
    override val itemsList : MutableLiveData<List<JSONChildOne>>
}
```